# Extracting the message XML in Axis1

Tags: axis

I am running Axis 1.2.1 (not axis2) to generate classes for a webservice client using a .wsdl file.

I'd like to be able to save down the raw xml data I receive and send, preferably as a string so that I can save it into a database as a CLOB.

I've tried following this tutorial:

http://proghowto.com/axis-client-request-and-response-logging

however my handler doesn't get invoked. I pretty much duplicated the code from the tutorial.

except for class names and the qname class(how do I set this to the correct value?)